Integral representations of Dirichlet L-function of quantum modular forms
It's known that holomorphic Eisenstein series for odd weight vanish in their lattice sum representation. However, its definition can be extended to allow for odd integers via its $q$-expansion
$$G_k=2\zeta(k)+\frac{(2\pi i)^k}{\Gamma(k)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_{k-1}(n)q^n,$$
which doesn't vanish for odd $k$, but is not a modular form anymore due to the appearance of a modularity gap (see: Shun Shimomura, "Modularity gap for Eisenstein series" Proceedings of the Japan Academy, Series A 86, No. 4, 79-84 (2010), MR2657331,  Zbl 1214.11098), making them quantum modular forms. We can define its Dirichlet series, which converges for sufficiently large s in $\sum_n \frac{\sigma_{k-1}(n)}{n^s}$. In the case of modular forms, we can meromorphically extend this to all of $\mathbb{C}$ via the Mellin transform of its seed function to get an integral representation of the $L$-function. Can this be extended to the case of quantum modular forms? Or in particular to Eisenstein series of odd weight?

$$\sum_n\sigma_{k-1}(n)/n^s=\zeta(s)\zeta(s-(k-1))$$
